# Finding minimum value of a function

Tags: derivatives, calculus

Consider $F$ is a function of $x$. To find the minimum value of $x$ which produces a minimum value of $F$, we are required to do $dF/dx = 0$. (Differentiate $F$ with respect to $x$)

Why do we do this and why does it produce minimum value for both $x$ and $F$?

Do we ALWAYS do this for getting minimum value for all functions?

Comment: Draw a graph of any function that has a minimum and you will see why.  Or a function that approaches a number e.g 1/x^2

Comment: This is a maths question, so belongs on Mathematics StackExchange, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Few things:

1. Differentiating a function and finding where it equal to zero is a way to find an **extremum** not just the minimum value.
2. Its impotent to note this is **not** the smallest (or biggest) value your function can take. it only takes a Minimum or Maximum value compared to other neighboring points.

Now, to answer your question we need to use calculus's definition of a derivative:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx} $$
-where 'dx' is what we call infinitesimal, meaning approaching zero.

an intuitive way to think about this is to think about how we define a slope of a linear function (remember from school that the slope is: $m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} $). you can see how the expression above is just that same slop you know just calculated between two very close together points on a function.

[image]

Now that we know that a derivative represent the slope of a function at x (in its very close vicinity) we can think where does this slope equal zero?

well, simply the points where rising stops and decent begins (or vice versa). points of extremum.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you for explaining. Can you please also explain why we would need to take a second derivative? For example I have a function, who's stable condition is found by taking the second derivative of the function and setting it to 0. I know that system stability is not the same as extreme value, so why are we taking derivative (2nd derivative to be exact)

Answer (score 2):

**Confusion about x**

First, you are confused here "To find **the minimum value of x** which produces a minimum value of F, we are required to do dF/dx = 0. (Differentiate F with respect to x)" and here "Why do we do this and why does it produce minimum value for **both x** and F?".

You are minimizing only the function here with respect of x, which means, that x is a free parameter, which you don't care if is bigger or smaller, instead you want to find which value of it, makes the function smaller.

Check the following image of the graphic of the value of F(x) (height) as we move through x (from left to right):

[image: First]

it is clear from here that the minimum of F(x) is around x= 0.3 more or less, which definitely is not the minimum x, since x=0.2 is smaller and x=0 or x=-10 and so on..., so you should realize it doesn't make sense to talk of a minimum of x, since it is a free parameter, and can take any value.

---

**How do we find minimums?**

No, we do not always do that alone to find the minimum value for all functions, the differentiation, gives us the slope of the function at that point. So when you fix the dF/dx=0 you are searching for points with slope 0 ($x_{min}$ where the function is totally horizontal), which from the next picture is easy to see, that can be maximums, minimums or what is called saddle points:

[image: Second Image]

so finally to find a minimum, you need the slope to be 0 (dF/dx=0) and then that both the near points in the right ($x=x_{min}$ + small) and the left ($x=x_{min}$ - small) give a higher value for the function, so that the function has a U form, instead than a Ո form (where it would be a maximum).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the notion of the derivative as the value of the slope tangent to the graph at the point of differentiation you understand that zero derivative at a point means zero slope tangent to the graph at that point. That is called an extremum point which can be one of three:

1. local minimum
2. local maximum
3. inflection point
   The first derivative vanishing does not tell you which point it is. For that you need to either check the value of the function in the vicinity of the extremum x-value, or you can use the second derivative test to distinguish between a maximum and a minimum